# Adding a notification for pending reviews

Tags: feature-request

I'm not sure if there is currently such a feature and for some reason doesn't work for me but would it be possible to add a functionality that shows some kind of alert when there are pending reviews (first posts/late posts)?

Currently the only way I can check if there are pending reviews is by checking the link every few minutes which is inconvenient.

Comment: @OlinLathrop All I'm asking is to add some kind of notification for pending reviews because currently there is none shown, at least not for me.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Maybe my phrasing was not good but I have the feeling that you are being hostile against me and I don't know why. A simple "your post doesn't make much sense, try to rephrase" or something would suffice.

Comment: @alexan_e Kalimera! Olin's comments often come over as hostile. If you feel it's inappropriate you can always flag it as offensive or not constructive. (This time I already did)

Comment: @GeertGoeteyn It's just that I try my best to help with the operation of this forum and sometimes I feel that I'm not welcomed. Maybe it's just the way some people express themselves and it comes off as hostile although this was not the intention but it still makes me sad. These are international forums so there are many foreigners that don't speak English as good as they should or can't express/explain a question properly, I think they shouldn't be treated harshly.

Comment: This is a international forum, but the language is still english. No, everyone doesn't have the right to post here whether they can speak English or not. Poor English is quite annoying to read for those that are fluent in the language. That may not be fair to those who write English poorly due to no fault of their own, but it is still true nonetheless. In your case, your original version was a runon sentence that was difficult to parse. That doesn't belong here regardless of the reason it happened. It may not be fair to you, but its also not fair to us to have to read it.

Comment: To answer the question as to why my tone was hostile instead of something nicer like *please try to rephrase* is because there was no excuse for it.  The issue wasn't unfamiliarity with English, but rather just dumping stream of conciousness on us in words without any sentence struture.  I'm sure you break up thought into sentences in Greek too.  You should have been able to see this for yourself and never posted something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The pending reviews are so few that a notification isn't really worth while. The site isn't really geared towards badge hunters, and the handful that dedicate themselves to ad-hoc moderating, will often check/refresh the page at their leisure. A review doesn't have the same urgency as a flag does, so it does not need a notification. IMHO.

Comment: Well, there's always the extremes - smaller sites don't really see that much, but StackOverflow will have way too much (and they really need it). I think they're working on *something* for that

Comment: `The site isn't really geared towards badge hunters` I hope this comment was not intended towards me because it is certainly not the case.

Comment: No, it wasn't intended towards anyone specifically, nor do I think badge-hunting is a bad thing @alexan_e